# How to programmatically obtain App Store Connect Team ID

Tags: ios, xcode, bash, shell, terminal

I need it for the `team_id` parameter in the `fastlane pilot upload` command [documented here](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/pilot/#usage).

The goal is to automate bootstrapping CI for a new app, and I was able to programmatically extract the `dev_portal_team_id` from the provisioning profile, but I'm not able to find the `team_id` anywhere.

Comment: Would also love insight on this.